# C# Class/Object passing (Array of Objects)

Tags: c#, arrays, object

Right so i have a class I'm using to store a set of values

```
public class dataSet
 {
  public int Number;
  public double Decimal;
  public string Text;
  //etc...
 }
```

Then I've made an array of type dataSet

```
public static dataSet[] dataOne = new dataSet[100];
```

And i'm trying to sort the array of dataOne relevant to the values stored in the `int` Number stored within dataSet.
I have a sort algorithm ready but i'm struggling to pass in the values stored solely in `dataOne.Number` so it just ends up being an integer array that i'm passing to the sort.
I'm a total noob at programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

I need to call my sort function by passing it in the array of `dataOne.Number` if this is possible? So it's basically just passing the sort function an `int[]`

Comment: I would recommend looking at my answer again before proceeding with your accepted answer. Better to use standard sort methods if you can and defining your object as IComparable is in my opinion the best way to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, I appreciate your answer it's just I'm limited with not being able to use inbuilt sorting methods in this particular instance. Else i'm sure yours would have been perfect for doing what i was asking. Thanks.

Comment: How is it you can't use Array.Sort? It is within the System namespace, which you're surely using. Unless it is for school or an interview?

Comment: It's for school haha. I am aware of it's capabilities otherwise.

Comment: Then implementing IComparable would probably look sketchy to the professor anyways. A little bit too advanced I would guess if you're working on writing your own sorting methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow why you can't use Linq. But that forces you do to something like this:

```
var numberValues = new List<int>();
foreach(var dataItem in dataOne)
{
    numberValues.Add(dataItem.Number);
}
```

Then you could pass `numberValues.ToArray()` to your sort method.

With Linq it would just be

```
dataOne.Select(d => d.Number).ToArray()
```

Comment: Will give this a try thanks, seems like it could work.

Comment: Hi, thanks this has helped best for my simple mind. Not trying to do anything too complicated here haha.

Answer (score 3):

Give you already have data into your array named `dataOne`, you could try:

### Linq Solution

Use `linq` to sort it, try this:

```
dataOne = dataOne.OrderBy(x => x.Number).ToArray();
```

Remember to add the namespace `System.Linq` to have access into these methods.

`OrderBy` allows you to pass an expression to sort data and it will return an `IOrderedEnumerable`. The `ToArray` will convert it to an `array`.

### Not Linq Solution

If you are not allowed to use Linq. You could implement an class that implements `IComparer<T>` and implement the method `Compare` which takes two generics arguments. Use an instance of this comparer type to sort your data.

For sample, since you have your `dataSet` type defined, you could implement the comparer:

```
public class DataSetComparer : IComparer<dataSet>
{
    public int Compare(dataSet x, dataSet y)
    {
        // define the logic to sort here...
        return x.Number.CompareTo(y.Number);
    }
}
```

And then, use the comparer on the `Array.Sort` method:

```
Array.Sort(dataSet, new NumberComparer());
```

It will order your dataSets.

Comment: I think you should comment using `Linq` to your answer

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. Forgot to mention i'm limited by not using inbuilt sorting functions.

Comment: @publicMan If you need the answer relative to the sort algorithm code you've already written, you need to supply that code for us to see as part of your question.

Comment: Yeah, Linq is off limits for me unfortunately. Just wanting to know how to pass the dataOne.Number array to my sort function. It needs to be passed into the sort function as an integer array.

Comment: I've updated my answer to a non-linq solution as well. It is not handy, but it works. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should have dataset implement IComparable that way you can easily just do...

```
dataOne = dataOne.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

OR...

```
Array.Sort(dataOne);
```

Here is how to implement IComparable...

```
public class dataSet : IComparable
{
    public int Number;
    public double Decimal;
    public string Text;

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 1;
        dataSet other = obj as dataSet;
        if (other != null) 
            return this.Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Object is not a dataSet");
    }
}
```